# .Net core framework version vs Nuget packages version + IIS

Tags: iis, .net-core, nuget

I am developing a.Net Core application targeting .Net Core 1.1.

Looking at my Nuget packages, I see that several packages would need to be updated such as:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore from 1.1.6 to 2.1.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore from 1.1.5 to 2.1.0

I thought that packages versions were inline with the targeted framework, so several questions:
Could a project targeting .Net Core 1.1 could have packages marked as v2.x.x. Is there any correlation between the framework version and the packages versions?

If I update for example Microsoft.ApsNetCore package to v2.1.0, would I need to change my project targeted framework?

Is it even correct that I am offered updates to v2.x.x nuget packages since I have specifically chosen a .Net Core 1.1 project. Shouldn't it be greyed instead?

Thank you for your feedback, all this versioning for .Net Core is very confusing.

Concerning IIS, I thought that if i was using Nuget packages version 1.1.4 for example, I had to be sure that the corresponding windows hosting bundle was installed on IIS to make the site working properly. Am i correct?

One last question, after upgrading some of my nuget packages in my project, I had to update the IIS by installing the [hosting bundle v1.1.8](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/runtime-1.1.8) in order to deploy my project. However, when it is getting installed, I have now 2 more runtimes  (1.0.11 and 1.1.8), Any reason for that?

How do I know which one is getting used by IIS?

At last when i run `dotnet --version` on IIS, I get the following:

```
...>dotnet --version

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 1.1.0
```

Is it correct, shouldn't it be 1.1.8?

Thank you

Sylvain

Comment: You are still using a very old .NET Core SDK (1.1.0). Even if you are writing .NET Core 1.1 apps, you should now upgrade to the latest SDK. Then you can learn the basic concepts from Rick's blog post https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Jun/05/Which-NET-Core-Runtime-Download-do-you-need

Comment: Thank you @LexLi. I have already updating my IIS to 1.1.8 runtime but the dotnet --version keeps returning 1.1.0....